# @media screen css not working

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
```

code CSS style.css:

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
         #top {
                 background-image:url(img/DESPRE-NOI.png);
                 width:400px;
                 height:38px;
                 margin-left:36%;
                 margin-top: 20%;
              }
}



@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
             #top {
                     background-image:url(img/DESPRE-NOI.png);
                     width:400px;
                     height:38px;
                     margin-left:36%;
                     margin-top: 2%;
                  }
    }
```

I want to apply `margin-top: X value` for two different resolutions and does not work.

This is the link:

http://test.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

Do you know what to do to make it work?

I do not understand what does not work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that the order that you are following on your CSS? Because if it is, that may be the problem. Move the code for the `min-width:1300px` over the code for the `min-width:1440px`. Both rules have the same weight, and the 1300 one appears later, so it will apply that one.

Comment: Your code works, but you will want to switch the larger media query to be on the bottom so it does not get overwritten.

Comment: It Works
To make him responsive ... I have to do the same for all possible resolutions?